# Export multiple clips from one video as separate files

Tags: video, video-editor, software-recommendation, linux, export

I'm looking for video editing software with a GUI that will fit my needs.

I've downloaded the video of the public comments from our most recent local city council meeting. 17 people gave public comments.

Here's basically what I want to do:

1. Create 16 breakpoints, separating each individual's comments.
2. Select/highlight those 17 clips.
3. Click 'export selected clips to directory'.
4. Choose the directory and click 'save'.
5. Go to the grocery store .
6. Get home & go to the folder on my computer with 17 files named `comment-1.mp4`, `comment-2.mp4`, `comment-3.mp4`, ... `comment-17.mp4`.
7. Upload them to my site / youtube / whatever.

**I'm using Ubuntu 19.10.**

- I have tried Kdenlive, which just froze when adding a 30-minute video, and I don't know if it has batch export anyway
- I tried Blender, and couldn't figure out a way to batch export like this. I was able to export clips one at a time, but it was extremely cumberson
- I'm now using Shotcut, which has made exporting clips one at a time super easy, but I can't figure out how to (or if I can do) a batch export as described above

I've looked at several different articles about editing software, and I can't seem to find this functionality listed. I'm not sure I'm searching with the correct terms.

1. Is there software for linux / ubuntu that will do what I want (with a GUI)? Which software?
2. If Shotcut can do it, how?

My preference is open source software. Free, too.

Comment: I don't need it to go to the grocery store or upload them for me, though that would be great! lol

Comment: Shotcut does it pretty easily https://forum.shotcut.org/t/export-one-track/7503/3 Just hadn't found the right search terms yet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it with shotcut. Credit to: https://forum.shotcut.org/t/export-one-track/7503/3

## Steps

1. Load video into shotcut
2. click+drag video down to timeline
3. move playhead to desired position & Split at Playead (S)
4. click on a clip I want to export, then Copy (C)
5. Open Playlist view (from top bar)
6. press the plus (+) button in the bottom left, at the bottom of the playlist view
7. Click the export tab
8. In the 'From' dropdown (where it says Timeline or Source), I choose 'Each Playlist Item'
9. Click 'Export File'
10. Choose location, file name, and click 'Save'